# Ignore integer within regex match

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'm creating a regex to process the line below as read from a file.

> 30/05/2014  17:58:19 418087******2093 No415000345536  5,000.00

I have successfully created the regex but my issue is that the string may sometimes appear as below with a slight addition (bold highlight)

> 31/05/2014  15:06:29 410741******7993 **0027200004750** No415100345732  1,500.00

Please assist in altering the pattern to ignore the integer of 13 digits that I don't need.

Below is my regex pattern

> `((?:(?:[0-2]?\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\/.](?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\d{1}\d{1}\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\d{3})))(?![\d])(\s+)((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)(\s+)(\d{6})(\*{6})(\d{4})(\s+)(No)(\d+)(\s+)([+-]?\d*\.\d+)(?![-+0-9\.])`

Advice and contribution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think that what have you used is so complicated regex pattern?

Comment: Do you want to **validate** the values as well or just want to extract/match the value? use `\d{13}?` to make it **optional** in between.

Comment: @user3218114 if I use \d{13} it will only consider it as a match. I would like to achieve a "delete or ignore" of sought using regex.

Comment: Do you want to validate the values as well?

Comment: Yes I do want to validate

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression in question was most likely created using a regular expression builder.

Here is your regular expression reduced to its component parts, simplified and with support for both variants of valid strings.

1. Date with a not complete validation (invalid days in month still possible):

   ```
   (?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[-:\/.](?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[-:\/.](?:19|20)\d\d
   ```
2. Whitespace(s) between date and time:

   ```
   [\t ]+
   ```

   `\s` matches also newline characters and other not often used whitespaces which is the reason why I'm using `[\t ]+` instead of `\s`.
3. Time with at least hour and minute with a not complete validation (leap second, AM or PM with invalid hour):

   ```
   (?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:[\t ]?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?
   ```
4. Whitespace(s), number with 4 digits, 6 asterisk, number with 4 digits, whitespace(s):

   ```
   [\t ]+\d{6}\*{6}\d{4}[\t ]+
   ```
5. Optionally a number with 13 digits not marked for backreferencing:

   ```
   (?:\d{13}[\t ]+)?
   ```
6. Number with undetermined number of digits, whitespace(s), optional plus or minus sign, floating point number (without exponent):

   ```
   No\d+[\t ]+[+-]?[\d,.]+
   ```

And here is the entire expression with 2 additionally added pairs of parentheses to mark the strings of real interest for further processing.

```
((?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[-:\/.](?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[-:\/.](?:19|20)\d\d[\t ]+(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:[\t ]?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?[\t ]+\d{6}\*{6}\d{4}[\t ]+)(?:\d{13}[\t ]+)?(No\d+[\t ]+[+-]?[\d,.]+)
```

The first marking group matches:

```
30/05/2014 17:58:19 418087******2093 
31/05/2014 15:06:29 410741******7993
```

`\1` or `$1` can be used to reference this part of entire found string.

The second marking group matches:

```
No415000345536 5,000.00
No415100345732 1,500.00
```

`\2` or `$2` can be used to reference this part of entire found string.

Hint: `(`...`)` is a marking group. `(?:`...`)` is a non-marking group because of `?:` immediately after opening parenthesis.

Comment: For the OP: You could remove most of the `?:` and could use the groups to fetch each number: `(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[-:\/.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[-:\/.]((?:19|20)\d\d)[\t ]+([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?(?:[\t ]?(am|AM|pm|PM))?[\t ]+(\d{6}\*{6}\d{4})[\t ]+(?:\d{13}[\t ]+)?No(\d+)[\t ]+([+-]?[\d,.]+)`

Comment: Thank you very much Mofi. You solution works best for me